# Hibernate querySingleResult not returning results

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm having problem why this Hibernate query fails (provided that other model queries work fine):

```
UserRoles u = (UserRoles) this.commonDAO.querySingleResult("SELECT u FROM UserRoles u where username = :id", QueryParams.c().add("id", user.getId()));
```

When checked `u` is `null`

Where doing a SQL query,

```
SELECT role_name, username
  FROM user_roles WHERE username = 'johnsmith';
```

returns the row.

Comment: Did you turn on full hibernate tracing to see the executed sql and the bind parameter's value?

Comment: Have you tried to pass the constant `johnsmith` instead of `user.getId()`?

Comment: @AlexeyMalev Yes, I can the values now, apparently UserRoles did not have a default constructor--I am still open for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the default constructor fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a search by `username` like

```
UserRoles u = (UserRoles) this.commonDAO.querySingleResult("SELECT u FROM UserRoles u where username = :username", QueryParams.c().add("username", user.getUsername()));
```

Comment: You mean my query is wrong? Apparently it worked, when I added the default constructor.

Comment: @xybrek I mean your code looks confusing because you pass `ID` instead of `username`.